# Как менять тип относительно входящих данных? typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datepicker, state

В функцию `onChange` приходит переменная `dates` зависящая от атрибута `selectsRange (reactDatePicker)`. Если `selectsRange === true` в `dates` приходит массив с 2-мя `Date`, а без просто `Date`.

```
type IOnChangeRange = [Date | null, Date | null]
type IOnChangeSingle = Date | null
```

Я пытался сделать так, но так не работает. Работает только по отдельности.

```
  const onChange = (dates: IOnChangeRange | IOnChangeSingle) => {
    if(selectsRange){
      const [start, end] = dates;
      setStartDate(start);
      setEndDate(end);
    } else {
      setStartDate(dates);
    }
  };
```

Подскажите как сделать правильно прописать типы. Выходит ошибка на строке: `const [start, end] = dates;`:

```
Type 'IOnChangeRange | IOnChangeSingle' is not an array type.
```

и на строке `setStartDate(dates)`:

```
Argument of type 'IOnChangeRange | IOnChangeSingle' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date | null>'.
  Type 'IOnChangeRange' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date | null>'.
    Type '[Date | null, Date | null]' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такое решение. Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но сработало.

```
const onChange = (dates: IOnChangeRange | IOnChangeSingle) => {
    if(Array.isArray(dates)){
      const [start, end] = dates;
      setStartDate(start);
      setEndDate(end);
    } else {
      setStartDate(dates);
    }
  };
```